# Radix-2 FFT in C

Tags: performance, beginner, c, signal-processing

I'm a beginner in C programming. I am current trying to work on a project requiring 1024-point FFT implementation using radix-2, Decimation-in-frequency. I attach the FFT function C code. How can I increase the performance by modifying the C code?

```
#include "i_cmplx.h"         /* definition of the complex type */  
#include "twiddle1024.h"    /* quantised and scaled Twiddle factors */
#define LL 1024             /* Maximum length of FFT */ 

/* fft radix-2 funtion using Decimation In Frequency */

//#pragma CODE_SECTION(fft, "mycode"); // Makes the program run from internal memory

void fft(COMPLEX *Y, int N) /* FFT(input sample array, # of points)     */
    {
    int temp1R, temp1I, temp2R,temp2I;  /* 32 bits temporary storage for */
                                       /* intermediate results          */                  
    short tempR, tempI, c, s;      /* 16 bits temporary storages    */
    /* variables */
    int TwFStep,  /* Step between twiddle factors */
        TwFIndex, /* Index of twiddle factors */
        BLStep,    /* Step for incrementing butterfly index */
        BLdiff,   /* Difference between upper and lower butterfly legs */
        upperIdx,
        lowerIdx, /* upper and lower indexes of buterfly leg */ 
        i, j, k;  /* loop control variables */

    BLdiff=N;
    TwFStep=1;
    for(k=N;k>1;k=(k>>1)) /* Do Log(base 2)(N) Stages */
        {
        BLStep=BLdiff;
        BLdiff=BLdiff>>1; 
        TwFIndex=0;
        for(j=0;j<BLdiff;j++)/* Nbr of twiddle factors to use=BLDiff  */
            {
            c=w[TwFIndex].real;
            s=w[TwFIndex].imag;
            TwFIndex=TwFIndex+TwFStep;                 
            /* Now do N/BLStep butterflies */  
            for(upperIdx=j;upperIdx<N;upperIdx+=BLStep)
                {                              
/* Calculations inside this loop avoid overflow by shifting left once
   the result of every adittion/substration and by shifting left 15 
   places the result of every multiplication. Double precision temporary
   results (32-bit) are used in order to avoid losing information because
   of overflow. Final DFT result is scaled by N (number of points), i.e.,
   2^(Nbr of stages) =2^(log(base 2) N) = N                             */

                lowerIdx=upperIdx+BLdiff;
                temp1R     = (Y[upperIdx].real - Y[lowerIdx].real)>>1;
                temp2R     = (Y[upperIdx].real + Y[lowerIdx].real)>>1;
                Y[upperIdx].real  =  (short) temp2R;
                temp1I     = (Y[upperIdx].imag - Y[lowerIdx].imag)>>1;
                temp2I     = (Y[upperIdx].imag + Y[lowerIdx].imag)>>1;
                Y[upperIdx].imag  =  (short) temp2I;
                temp2R     = (c*temp1R - s*temp1I)>>15;
                Y[lowerIdx].real  = (short) temp2R;
                temp2I     = (c*temp1I + s*temp1R)>>15;
                Y[lowerIdx].imag  =  (short) temp2I;
                }
            }
            TwFStep = TwFStep<<1; /* update separation of twiddle factors)*/
        }

/* bit reversal for resequencing data */

    j=0;
   for (i=1;i<(N-1);i++)
    {
      k=N/2;
      while (k<=j)
        {
         j = j-k;
         k=k/2;
         }
      j=j+k;
      if (i<j)
        {
         tempR=Y[j].real;
         tempI=Y[j].imag;
         Y[j].real=Y[i].real;
         Y[j].imag=Y[i].imag;
         Y[i].real=tempR;
         Y[i].imag=tempI;
         }
      }
    return;
    }
```

Source file:

```
twiddle1024.h

/* This file defines the 512 complex twiddle factors used by the program */

//twiddle1024.h
struct
    {
    short real; /* 32767*cos(2*pi*n) term */
    short imag; /* 32767*sin (2*pi*n)term */
    }
 w[]={32767,0,
      32767,-201,
      32766,-402,
      32762,-603,
      32758,-804,
      32753,-1005,
      32746,-1206,
      32738,-1407,
      32729,-1608,
      32718,-1809,
      32706,-2009,
      32693,-2210,
      32679,-2411,
      32664,-2611,
      32647,-2811,
      32629,-3012,
      32610,-3212,
      32590,-3412,
      32568,-3612,
      32546,-3812,
      32522,-4011,
      32496,-4211,
      32470,-4410,
      32442,-4609,
      32413,-4808,
      32383,-5007,
      32352,-5205,
      32319,-5404,
      32286,-5602,
      32251,-5800,
      32214,-5998,
      32177,-6195,
      32138,-6393,
      32099,-6590,
      32058,-6787,
      32015,-6983,
      31972,-7180,
      31927,-7376,
      31881,-7571,
      31834,-7767,
      31786,-7962,
      31737,-8157,
      31686,-8351,
      31634,-8546,
      31581,-8740,
      31527,-8933,
      31471,-9127,
      31415,-9319,
      31357,-9512,
      31298,-9704,
      31238,-9896,
      31177,-10088,
      31114,-10279,
      31050,-10469,
      30986,-10660,
      30920,-10850,
      30853,-11039,
      30784,-11228,
      30715,-11417,
      30644,-11605,
      30572,-11793,
      30499,-11980,
      30425,-12167,
      30350,-12354,
      30274,-12540,
      30196,-12725,
      30118,-12910,
      30038,-13095,
      29957,-13279,
      29875,-13463,
      29792,-13646,
      29707,-13828,
      29622,-14010,
      29535,-14192,
      29448,-14373,
      29359,-14553,
      29269,-14733,
      29178,-14912,
      29086,-15091,
      28993,-15269,
      28899,-15447,
      28803,-15624,
      28707,-15800,
      28610,-15976,
      28511,-16151,
      28411,-16326,
      28311,-16500,
      28209,-16673,
      28106,-16846,
      28002,-17018,
      27897,-17190,
      27791,-17361,
      27684,-17531,
      27576,-17700,
      27467,-17869,
      27357,-18037,
      27246,-18205,
      27133,-18372,
      27020,-18538,
      26906,-18703,
      26791,-18868,
      26674,-19032,
      26557,-19195,
      26439,-19358,
      26320,-19520,
      26199,-19681,
      26078,-19841,
      25956,-20001,
      25833,-20160,
      25708,-20318,
      25583,-20475,
      25457,-20632,
      25330,-20788,
      25202,-20943,
      25073,-21097,
      24943,-21251,
      24812,-21403,
      24680,-21555,
      24548,-21706,
      24414,-21856,
      24279,-22006,
      24144,-22154,
      24008,-22302,
      23870,-22449,
      23732,-22595,
      23593,-22740,
      23453,-22884,
      23312,-23028,
      23170,-23170,
      23028,-23312,
      22884,-23453,
      22740,-23593,
      22595,-23732,
      22449,-23870,
      22302,-24008,
      22154,-24144,
      22006,-24279,
      21856,-24414,
      21706,-24548,
      21555,-24680,
      21403,-24812,
      21251,-24943,
      21097,-25073,
      20943,-25202,
      20788,-25330,
      20632,-25457,
      20475,-25583,
      20318,-25708,
      20160,-25833,
      20001,-25956,
      19841,-26078,
      19681,-26199,
      19520,-26320,
      19358,-26439,
      19195,-26557,
      19032,-26674,
      18868,-26791,
      18703,-26906,
      18538,-27020,
      18372,-27133,
      18205,-27246,
      18037,-27357,
      17869,-27467,
      17700,-27576,
      17531,-27684,
      17361,-27791,
      17190,-27897,
      17018,-28002,
      16846,-28106,
      16673,-28209,
      16500,-28311,
      16326,-28411,
      16151,-28511,
      15976,-28610,
      15800,-28707,
      15624,-28803,
      15447,-28899,
      15269,-28993,
      15091,-29086,
      14912,-29178,
      14733,-29269,
      14553,-29359,
      14373,-29448,
      14192,-29535,
      14010,-29622,
      13828,-29707,
      13646,-29792,
      13463,-29875,
      13279,-29957,
      13095,-30038,
      12910,-30118,
      12725,-30196,
      12540,-30274,
      12354,-30350,
      12167,-30425,
      11980,-30499,
      11793,-30572,
      11605,-30644,
      11417,-30715,
      11228,-30784,
      11039,-30853,
      10850,-30920,
      10660,-30986,
      10469,-31050,
      10279,-31114,
      10088,-31177,
      9896,-31238,
      9704,-31298,
      9512,-31357,
      9319,-31415,
      9127,-31471,
      8933,-31527,
      8740,-31581,
      8546,-31634,
      8351,-31686,
      8157,-31737,
      7962,-31786,
      7767,-31834,
      7571,-31881,
      7376,-31927,
      7180,-31972,
      6983,-32015,
      6787,-32058,
      6590,-32099,
      6393,-32138,
      6195,-32177,
      5998,-32214,
      5800,-32251,
      5602,-32286,
      5404,-32319,
      5205,-32352,
      5007,-32383,
      4808,-32413,
      4609,-32442,
      4410,-32470,
      4211,-32496,
      4011,-32522,
      3812,-32546,
      3612,-32568,
      3412,-32590,
      3212,-32610,
      3012,-32629,
      2811,-32647,
      2611,-32664,
      2411,-32679,
      2210,-32693,
      2009,-32706,
      1809,-32718,
      1608,-32729,
      1407,-32738,
      1206,-32746,
      1005,-32753,
      804,-32758,
      603,-32762,
      402,-32766,
      201,-32767,
      0,-32768,
      -201,-32767,
      -402,-32766,
      -603,-32762,
      -804,-32758,
      -1005,-32753,
      -1206,-32746,
      -1407,-32738,
      -1608,-32729,
      -1809,-32718,
      -2009,-32706,
      -2210,-32693,
      -2411,-32679,
      -2611,-32664,
      -2811,-32647,
      -3012,-32629,
      -3212,-32610,
      -3412,-32590,
      -3612,-32568,
      -3812,-32546,
      -4011,-32522,
      -4211,-32496,
      -4410,-32470,
      -4609,-32442,
      -4808,-32413,
      -5007,-32383,
      -5205,-32352,
      -5404,-32319,
      -5602,-32286,
      -5800,-32251,
      -5998,-32214,
      -6195,-32177,
      -6393,-32138,
      -6590,-32099,
      -6787,-32058,
      -6983,-32015,
      -7180,-31972,
      -7376,-31927,
      -7571,-31881,
      -7767,-31834,
      -7962,-31786,
      -8157,-31737,
      -8351,-31686,
      -8546,-31634,
      -8740,-31581,
      -8933,-31527,
      -9127,-31471,
      -9319,-31415,
      -9512,-31357,
      -9704,-31298,
      -9896,-31238,
      -10088,-31177,
      -10279,-31114,
      -10469,-31050,
      -10660,-30986,
      -10850,-30920,
      -11039,-30853,
      -11228,-30784,
      -11417,-30715,
      -11605,-30644,
      -11793,-30572,
      -11980,-30499,
      -12167,-30425,
      -12354,-30350,
      -12540,-30274,
      -12725,-30196,
      -12910,-30118,
      -13095,-30038,
      -13279,-29957,
      -13463,-29875,
      -13646,-29792,
      -13828,-29707,
      -14010,-29622,
      -14192,-29535,
      -14373,-29448,
      -14553,-29359,
      -14733,-29269,
      -14912,-29178,
      -15091,-29086,
      -15269,-28993,
      -15447,-28899,
      -15624,-28803,
      -15800,-28707,
      -15976,-28610,
      -16151,-28511,
      -16326,-28411,
      -16500,-28311,
      -16673,-28209,
      -16846,-28106,
      -17018,-28002,
      -17190,-27897,
      -17361,-27791,
      -17531,-27684,
      -17700,-27576,
      -17869,-27467,
      -18037,-27357,
      -18205,-27246,
      -18372,-27133,
      -18538,-27020,
      -18703,-26906,
      -18868,-26791,
      -19032,-26674,
      -19195,-26557,
      -19358,-26439,
      -19520,-26320,
      -19681,-26199,
      -19841,-26078,
      -20001,-25956,
      -20160,-25833,
      -20318,-25708,
      -20475,-25583,
      -20632,-25457,
      -20788,-25330,
      -20943,-25202,
      -21097,-25073,
      -21251,-24943,
      -21403,-24812,
      -21555,-24680,
      -21706,-24548,
      -21856,-24414,
      -22006,-24279,
      -22154,-24144,
      -22302,-24008,
      -22449,-23870,
      -22595,-23732,
      -22740,-23593,
      -22884,-23453,
      -23028,-23312,
      -23170,-23170,
      -23312,-23028,
      -23453,-22884,
      -23593,-22740,
      -23732,-22595,
      -23870,-22449,
      -24008,-22302,
      -24144,-22154,
      -24279,-22006,
      -24414,-21856,
      -24548,-21706,
      -24680,-21555,
      -24812,-21403,
      -24943,-21251,
      -25073,-21097,
      -25202,-20943,
      -25330,-20788,
      -25457,-20632,
      -25583,-20475,
      -25708,-20318,
      -25833,-20160,
      -25956,-20001,
      -26078,-19841,
      -26199,-19681,
      -26320,-19520,
      -26439,-19358,
      -26557,-19195,
      -26674,-19032,
      -26791,-18868,
      -26906,-18703,
      -27020,-18538,
      -27133,-18372,
      -27246,-18205,
      -27357,-18037,
      -27467,-17869,
      -27576,-17700,
      -27684,-17531,
      -27791,-17361,
      -27897,-17190,
      -28002,-17018,
      -28106,-16846,
      -28209,-16673,
      -28311,-16500,
      -28411,-16326,
      -28511,-16151,
      -28610,-15976,
      -28707,-15800,
      -28803,-15624,
      -28899,-15447,
      -28993,-15269,
      -29086,-15091,
      -29178,-14912,
      -29269,-14733,
      -29359,-14553,
      -29448,-14373,
      -29535,-14192,
      -29622,-14010,
      -29707,-13828,
      -29792,-13646,
      -29875,-13463,
      -29957,-13279,
      -30038,-13095,
      -30118,-12910,
      -30196,-12725,
      -30274,-12540,
      -30350,-12354,
      -30425,-12167,
      -30499,-11980,
      -30572,-11793,
      -30644,-11605,
      -30715,-11417,
      -30784,-11228,
      -30853,-11039,
      -30920,-10850,
      -30986,-10660,
      -31050,-10469,
      -31114,-10279,
      -31177,-10088,
      -31238,-9896,
      -31298,-9704,
      -31357,-9512,
      -31415,-9319,
      -31471,-9127,
      -31527,-8933,
      -31581,-8740,
      -31634,-8546,
      -31686,-8351,
      -31737,-8157,
      -31786,-7962,
      -31834,-7767,
      -31881,-7571,
      -31927,-7376,
      -31972,-7180,
      -32015,-6983,
      -32058,-6787,
      -32099,-6590,
      -32138,-6393,
      -32177,-6195,
      -32214,-5998,
      -32251,-5800,
      -32286,-5602,
      -32319,-5404,
      -32352,-5205,
      -32383,-5007,
      -32413,-4808,
      -32442,-4609,
      -32470,-4410,
      -32496,-4211,
      -32522,-4011,
      -32546,-3812,
      -32568,-3612,
      -32590,-3412,
      -32610,-3212,
      -32629,-3012,
      -32647,-2811,
      -32664,-2611,
      -32679,-2411,
      -32693,-2210,
      -32706,-2009,
      -32718,-1809,
      -32729,-1608,
      -32738,-1407,
      -32746,-1206,
      -32753,-1005,
      -32758,-804,
      -32762,-603,
      -32766,-402,
      -32767,-201};
```

Comment: Many people wrote optimized fft's. FFTW for instance. Can't you just use that?

Comment: [tag:reinventing-the-wheel]?

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Answer for the resequencing part of your code

This function worked like magic for me:

```
void bit_reverse_reorder(complex *Y, int N)
{
   unsigned i,j;
   for (i = 0, j = 0; i < N; i++) {
   if (i < j) 
   {
     tempR=Y[j].real;
     tempI=Y[j].imag;
     Y[j].real=Y[i].real;
     Y[j].imag=Y[i].imag;
     Y[i].real=tempR;
     Y[i].imag=tempI;

   }
   unsigned bit = ~i & (i + 1);

   unsigned rev = (N / 2) / bit;

   j ^= (N - 1) & ~(rev - 1);
  }
}
```

**About the compiler:**

If I was you I'll use the GCC compiler preferably version 5.x with the highest optimization levels `-O5` and try to use the `-ffast-math` it has its effect on arithmetic operations.